# Can not find symbol Finder

Tags: butterknife

I set up ButterKnife into Android Studio.

project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
...
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
```

And I have this:

> Error:(6, 28) error: cannot find symbol class Finder
>   in
>   ..\DetailActivity$$ViewBinder.java

I am trying:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.title_textview) TextView titleTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
...
        titleTextView.setText(movie.getTitle());
```

Comment: Why not using the same version in both dependencies? try `apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'`

Comment: @NeriaNachum , Thanks a lot! Problem solved!